# TFS Server 2012 and Promoting changes

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I started using TFS Team explorer 2012 and happen to notice a new process called **promoting**. As I understand it, the Team Explorer detect any changes made to the files outside of the TFS explorer and count them for promotion? Am I right?

How do I take care of the situation where I made a change to the file which is already checked out through TFS, then made a change via Windows Explorer\Notepad but dont want to include the changes made through the Windows Explorer\Notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While everything that discens said is correct, one thing bears explicit mention:  there is no change to the level of granularity of Team Foundation Server.  You still check out *files* and edit *files* and check-in *files*.

In your example, if you have a file checked out and you edit it in Notepad, the changes will be checked in.  There is no change here from previous behaviors.  There is no way to keep these changes from being checked in, short of saving the file with a different file name.

Answer (score 2):

This is a new feature of TFS 2012 called `Local Workspaces`.

You are correct in that changes made outside of visual studio can be included in the check-in by promoting them, if they are not already under source control.

If they are already in source control and you do **not** want to commit them, then you would need to right click the file and choose `Exclude`.  This will move the file from `Included Changes` into `Excluded Changes`.

If you do not like the new `Local Workspaces` you can tell TFS to go back to the old model of `Server Workspaces`:

- Open Team Explorer
- Go to Settings
- Under `Team Project Collection` select `Source Control`
- Click the `Workspace Settings Tab`
- Here you can choose the workspace type.

Comment: On Step 3:

Error

TF14044: Access Denied: User XY needs the AdminConfiguration global permission(s).